# Type 'HttpEvent<Student[]>' is not assignable to type 'Student[]'. Type 'HttpSentEvent' is not assignable to type 'Student[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

> Error TS2322  (TS) Type 'HttpEvent' is not assignable to
>   type 'Student[]'.   Type 'HttpSentEvent' is not assignable to type
>   'Student[]'.
>       Property 'length' is missing in type 'HttpSentEvent'.

I am getting above error in my line of code:

Declarations

```
 public Students: Array<Student> = [];
 model: any = {};


constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {
}

async  LoadStudentData() {
    var t = await this.httpService.get<Array<Student>>(URL, this.model).toPromise();

    this.Students = t;

}
```

Is there any way to do the casting?

Comment: what is Organization and Students type and relation?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for suggestions.

Modifying my await call as below **worked for me**

```
var t = await this.httpService.get<Student[]>(URL, { params: this.model, observe: 'body' })
        .toPromise();

this.Students = t;
```